Minimizing VSCode window on local machine slows down Python code with tqdm on remote server by 10x
I am using VSCode SSH remote connection to execute Python code on a server from my local computer. In the code, there is a loop that utilizes the tqdm library.
pbar = tqdm.tqdm(enumerate(test_corpus), total=file_len(corpus_file))
found = 0
for i, t in pbar:
    found_category = title_cat.get(text_to_id(t['title']), [])
    if not found_category:
        found_category = get_term_categories(text_to_id(t['title']), page_to_id_dict.get(text_to_id(t['title']), -1))
    
    if found_category:
        title_cat[text_to_id(t['title'])] = found_category
    else:
        if ":" in text_to_id(t['title']):
            title = text_to_id(t['title']).split(":")[1]
            found_category = get_term_categories(text_to_id(title), page_to_id_dict.get(text_to_id(title), -1))
    t['category'] = found_category
    if found_category:
        found += 1
        pbar.set_description(f'Found for: {found}/{i}')
    
    test_corpus_with_category.append(t)

The program normally prints progress information as follows:
4283431/5416593 [37:38<06:18, 2995.91it/s]
At this point, I minimize the VSCode window. At the same time, I immediately notice that in the Windows Task Manager, VSCode has switched to efficiency mode.
The most incredible thing is that the Python code running on the remote server slows down by more than 10 times:
5109244/5416593 [42:53<1:23:18, 61.48it/s]
If I bring the VSCode window back into focus (e.g., by clicking on it), everything returns to normal: VSCode is no longer in efficiency mode, and the Python code running on the remote server also returns to its original execution speed.
I cannot understand why the execution speed of the code on the remote server is so greatly affected, even if the local VSCode is set to efficiency mode due to Windows CPU scheduling strategy.
If I use commands like nohup to run the code on the remote server in the background (rather than in VSCode SSH terminal), then this issue won't occur.

What's wrong with this? If you have a full reproducible step-by-step and logging log, you can report what you think is the problem at GitHub.  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new/choose

what if you remove the progress message prints and just print a total-time-elapsed message, or less frequent rate-of-work status messages? is that faster? I wonder if the output being transmitted to local and Windows OS allocating less network priority to efficiency-mode processes is a thing? maybe you could write some dummy programs to test that hypothesis.
